# Indicate after swiping the last page in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have created a view pager with circle page indicator. Its working fine. 
Here is my new requirement : 
When i'am in last/first page and try to swipe for next/previous page, my screen should move at least 30% towards the swiped direction and come back to its original position as there are no more pages to navigate? Of course i have page indicators at top which tells where am i in available pages. I hope my requirement is clear. How can i achieve it ? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is automatic.  The OS has built in indicators to tell the user the views can't be swiped any further.  The OS will display a glow on the side of the screen, and the user can't pull further.

Not sure if you can create your own unique UI to handle this - the OS does provide a indicator out of the box.

Comment: Unless I somehow accidentally turned it off, I've used ViewPager for months and it has never automatically done an overswipe effect.  It does do it for GridView, TextView, and ListView though.

Comment: this depended on the OS, i check this with 2.3 & 4.1 devices and the implementation is different. in 2.3 there no indication at all , in 4.1 there is glow side affect,  I believe you will have to implement this by yourself

Comment: FWIW - this is called "Overscroll"

Answer (score 6):

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pagerListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        boolean lastPageChange = false;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels){
            int lastIdx = mPgScreenAdapter.getCount() - 1;

            Log.d(TAG, "pos:" + position);
            if(lastPageChange && position == lastIdx)
                PPIntent.changeScene(curAct, new Intent(curAct, LoginActivity.class), true);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected( int i) {
            pgText.setCurrentItem(i/2);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            int lastIdx = mPgScreenAdapter.getCount() - 1;

            int curItem = pgScreen.getCurrentItem();
            if(curItem==lastIdx /*&& lastPos==lastIdx*/  && state==1)   lastPageChange = true;
            else                                                         lastPageChange = false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: This works well , just that the code to start a new activity can be moved to pagescrollstatechanged inside the if condition since, onPageScrolled gets called multiple times..

Comment: Can you tell me how to toast ("this is first page") to user if user swipe first page of viewpager in backward direction.Thank you @icarus2n