# Android ViewPager when swiping on last screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Im having trouble figuring out how to capture a swipe event on the last page of a view pager.

Basically the requirement is that when the user is on the last page, and they try to swipe to get to the next page, the activity should close.

I've tried doing this onPageScrolled but I cant seem to differentiate a left or right swipe when in there. When on the last page, the user should still maintain the functionality to move to the previous page.

So basically the case is

```
When on last page
    if swipe prev (do normal behaviour)
    if swipe next (finish activity)
```

Can anyone provide any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should include an fake blank page to your `ViewPager`, when user swipes your actual last page, it comes to this fake one. When this fake one is visible finish the `Activity`.

You should try this way, if it does not work, I can give you an example code.

Comment: Not the kind of solution I was looking for but Ill give you the checkmark since no one else offered anything.

Comment: If you explain further I can edit the answer. Why don't you like it? It is easy and effective.

Comment: If you're using any kind of pager indicator, it shows as an extra item. Also, if you're overriding onDraw in a view pager to display a parallax image, it'll throw off the percentage of image scrolling.

Comment: You can give a -1 fake count to the indicator and handle onPageChange yourself to change the indicator. I'm sure it can be ignored in the onDraw function for the first page.

Comment: Hey, It's amazing idea, but I want a little help, if I have Indicator, it's possible remove the last indicator?

Comment: What kind of indicator are you using? If you're using a library, their source code is not that big. You can copy the source and modify for your needs.
They usually get the number of pages from the ViewPager automatically, you should trick that and have 1 less page.

Comment: Of course, look at the license of the library and don't forget to mention the lib in your licenses page even when you copy the source code.

Answer (score 19):

Here is working solution!!

Required variables

```
....
private boolean isLastPageSwiped;
private int counterPageScroll;
....
```

Inside **onPageScrolled** of **ViewPager**

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    //Here 6 is last position 
    if (position == 6 && positionOffset == 0 && !isLastPageSwiped){
        if(counterPageScroll != 0){
            isLastPageSwiped=true;
            //Next Activity here
        }
        counterPageScroll++;
    }else{
        counterPageScroll=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: : perfect solution.

Answer (score 9):

I am probably really late, but then this might help someone else down the line. I got the snippet from a question on stackoverflow, where in i am just tweaking the code a little bit.

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29137236/2683275).

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pagerListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    boolean lastPageChange = false;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels){
        int lastIdx = mPgScreenAdapter.getCount() - 1;

        Log.d(TAG, "pos:" + position);
        if(lastPageChange && position == lastIdx) {}

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected( int i) {
        pgText.setCurrentItem(i/2);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        int lastIdx = mPgScreenAdapter.getCount() - 1;

        int curItem = pgScreen.getCurrentItem();
        if(curItem==lastIdx  && state==1){
            lastPageChange = true;

            // i put this here since onPageScroll gets called a couple of times.
            finish();
        }else  { 
            lastPageChange = false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It's correct but when I come back last index to previous its also goes to the next activity.

Answer (score 5):

```
int lastPosition;
int currentPosition;


//View pager assign 
ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
//PageIndicatorView external https://github.com/romandanylyk
PageIndicatorView pageIndicatorView = findViewById(R.id.pageIndicatorView);


//customise pageIndicatorView design
pageIndicatorView.setAnimationType(AnimationType.THIN_WORM);
pageIndicatorView.setViewPager(viewPager);


//BannerAdapter is an custom adapter for viewpage i made.
//assign data here
BannerAdapter pagerAdapter = new BannerAdapter(this, banner, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {

            }
        });
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

//listener for View Pager
//this is where process of making the infinite loop
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            //assign position so that can be manipulated
            currentPosition = position;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //set pager indicator position here 
            pageIndicatorView.setSelection(position);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            //check state 0 mean no ongoing process
            if(state == 0){
                //check currentPosition == lastPosition to detect that scroll cant scroll anymore
                if(currentPosition == lastPosition){
                    int lastitem = banner.size() - 1;
                    //check position if either last item/first item
                    //and set viewpager current page as follow
                    if(currentPosition == lastitem){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    }else if(currentPosition == 0){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(lastitem);
                    }
                }else{
                    lastPosition = currentPosition;
                }
                Log.d("ScrollState", "currentPosition: " + currentPosition);
            }
            /*empty*/
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I also tried my luck to find solution. Here is working code.Hope it will help someone else:-

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    int curr = pager.getCurrentItem();
                    int lastReal = pager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1;

                    if (curr < lastReal) {
                        counter = 0;
                    } else if (curr == lastReal) {
                        counter++;

                        if (counter == 2) {

                            pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
                            pager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
                            counter = 0;
                        }


                    }
                }

            }
        });

        pagerIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

I used counter as global variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I created an abstract listener based on the solutions here. I wanted to do something when swiping right on the last page, or left on the first page.

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

abstract class PageChangeToUnavailablePageListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private int finalPageIndex;
    private boolean finalPageVisible = false;
    private boolean firstPageVisible = true;
    private int lastScrollState = 0;

    abstract void onUnavailablePageChangeOnLastPage();
    abstract void onUnavailablePageChangeOnFirstPage();

    public PageChangeToUnavailablePageListener(int finalPageIndex) {
        this.finalPageIndex = finalPageIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int i) {
        firstPageVisible = (i == 0);
        finalPageVisible = (i == finalPageIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        // The normal state sequence for changing pages is
        // DRAGGING (user starts drag), SETTLING (next page is chosen), IDLE (animation is complete).
        // No next page is chosen when dragging right on last page, or left on first page.
        // In this case the SETTLING state is missing and the sequence is (DRAGGING, IDLE).
        if (lastScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            // The user scrolled to an unavailable page.
            if (finalPageVisible) {
                onUnavailablePageChangeOnLastPage();
            } else if (firstPageVisible) {
                onUnavailablePageChangeOnFirstPage();
            }
        }
        lastScrollState = state;
    }
}
```

Comment: so, how to use this to my viewPager ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got an answer, i came across the same issue and this is what i did:
Incase you are using a viewpager and an activity with a class extending `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` you can use the `getItem(int position)` method to check if you reached the last page. This is also if you declared the `NUM_PAGES` and you can use it to detect the user has reached the last page.

Answer (score 0):

in Activity:

```
private static int MAX_LAYOUTS = 3;
private boolean isLastPageSwiped;
private int counterPageScroll;
```

In onCreate:

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if (position == MAX_LAYOUTS - 1 && positionOffset == 0 && !isLastPageSwiped) {
                    if (counterPageScroll != 0) {
                        isLastPageSwiped = true;

                        Intent intent = new Intent(OldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    counterPageScroll++;
                } else {
                    counterPageScroll = 0;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        };
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

i have also solution for these(in kotlin),

Example my tabview has 3 pages.

......

```
private var isLastPageSwiped = false
private var indexPageScroll = 0
```

......

```
    override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
        super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels)
        if (position == 2 && positionOffset == 0f && !isLastPageSwiped) {
            if (indexPageScroll != 0) {
                isLastPageSwiped = true
                //Next Activity here
                //You can perform your action on last page scroll.
            }
            indexPageScroll++
        } else {
            indexPageScroll = 0
        }
    }
```