# Duplicate activity records in stack

Tags: android, android-activity

when I am firing an activity through intent the activity instances is created multiple times (3) in the stack and this makes me click back button thrice to come to previous activity.
Im not able to figure out what is the reason behind this kindly help me.
this is the code snippet,

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(mIntent, Constants.B_Issue);
```

EDIT : Im using this in onPageScrolled

```
 @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(final int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        Log.e(TAG, " On Page Scrolled invoked ");
        posOffset = positionOffset;
        if (lastState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test.class);
            startActivityForResult(mIntent, Constants.TEST_WORK);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `startActivityForResult(mIntent, Constants.B_Issue);`use `startActivity(mIntent);`

Comment: Hi i have tried that too which gives the same result.

Comment: show full code.

Comment: Please check whether this code is called 3 times...

Comment: please share full code

Comment: Im using this in onPageScrolled @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(final int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                Log.e(TAG, " On Page Scrolled invoked ");
                posOffset=positionOffset;
                if (lastState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test.class);
     startActivityForResult(mIntent, Constants.TEST_WORK);
                }
            }

Answer (score 1):

Where have u called below code?

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(mIntent, Constants.B_Issue);
```

I think this code is called multiple times, which is creating multiple instances of activity.
I can help you more, if you can provide complete MainActivity.

Comment: Hi Jatin im firing this inside onPageScrolled  @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(final int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                Log.e(TAG, " On Page Scrolled invoked ");
                posOffset=positionOffset;
                if (lastState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test.class);
     startActivityForResult(mIntent, Constants.TEST_WORK);
                }
            }

Comment: And the orientation changes on moving to this Test Activity

Comment: May I know, any particular reason to write this code in onPageScrolled? Because, I think, we should find some other way to call other activity. Orientation change may be because you must have mentioned it in manifest file.

Comment: Im displaying series of images which when scrolled right will display the next image and when this reaches to the last image it will fire this activity through intent here is where the three instances are created for the fired activity.

Comment: Did u find any solution?

Comment: You need to apply few more checks, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674060/android-viewpager-when-swiping-on-last-screen specific to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40758115/3266929

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for going one activity to other;

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, B.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: I have added this in onPageScrolled which is called thrice

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, B.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Instead of this

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(mIntent, Constants.B_Issue);
```

Comment: i have tried that too , still it creates multiple instance of the same activity

Comment: this is where im firing the activity in Onpagescrolled                                                                                    @Override
 public void onPageScrolled(final int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                Log.e(TAG, " On Page Scrolled invoked ");
                posOffset=positionOffset;
                if (lastState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test.class);
     startActivityForResult(mIntent, Constants.TEST_WORK);
                }
            }

Comment: this onPageScrolled method might be called multiple times, check how many times the log you have put is printed in console. you need to write this code somewhere else.